# How to delete empty worksheets from a workbook in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm filling up my workbook with worksheets and I'm not able to figure out why empty sheets are coming up in my workbook.

- I need to delete empty sheets 
  OR
- Determine why empty sheets are being created.

Any help on this would be helpful.
[image: Output excel; Sheet1, Sheet3, Sheet5, Sheet7 are empty sheets]

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
workBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet));

//DataTable to Excel
                foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
                {
                    workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                    workSheet.Name = table.TableName;

                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                        {
                            workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (k + 1)] = table.Rows[i][k];
                        }
                    }
                    workBook.Worksheets.Add(workSheet);
                }

//Trying to delete empty sheets
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet in workBook.Sheets)
{
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    if (sheet.Cells.MaxRow == -1 && sheet.Cells.MaxColumn == -1)
    {
       sheet.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: not possible to delete empty cell just put some alert box

Comment: I don't want to delete empty cell, I want to delete all empty worksheets from the workbook.

Comment: because you are adding them at the beginning AND the end of the loop `.Worksheets.Add`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure how to add a worksheet without creating it. Can you help me with creating a worksheet and then adding it to a workbook with an example?

Answer (score 2):

Using MS Interop I do not see any properties for the `MaxRow` and `MaxCol`. So looking at your posted code, I am guessing you are getting errors as those properties do not exist. Is what you are looking for is a `UsedRange`. This will return a rectangle range that will contain all the cells in the worksheet that contain some values. If the used range returns 1 or less, then the sheet is empty. The code below will accomplish what you are asking. Hope this helps.

```
foreach (Worksheet sheet in xlWorkbook.Worksheets) {
  if (sheet.UsedRange.Count < 2) {
    sheet.Delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you JohnG, the solution that you suggested works. But rather than creating an empty sheet and then deleting it, it would be better not create it at all. I'm adding two worksheets (Worksheets.Add) in the foreach loop. I would like to know how to achieve this by calling just one Worksheets.Add.

Comment: First line inside the foreach, `if ((table.Columns == 0) && (table.Rows == 0)) { continue; }`